# Html 5, Animating between anchor points

Tags: html, animation, scroll, anchor

I'm thinking about making a website for my business where all the content is on one long page which the user will not be able to scroll through and you will have to navigate through the site by clicking the buttons which will then animate between the anchor points to the next page. I'm will make a long image with the home point being an office and the user then can go up into the sky then space for different pages.
So how would I stop the user from being able to scroll and how would I make it animate or slowly scroll between each anchor. Would it be possible to scroll horizontally as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to solve your problem by disabling temporally the scrolling functionality of the browser. You can achieve this by unbinding any event listeners associated with keypress or mouse scroll.

You can deny the mouse scroll to get triggered by preventing it's default action associated with the event handler. Technically this is how can be done in Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', disableScroll, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) { //IE event handler
        window.attachEvent('DOMMouseScroll', disableScroll);
    } else {
        window.onscroll = disableScroll;
    }
}

function disableScroll(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action to get triggered\
    }
    event.returnValue = false; // IE method
}

var keys = [37, 38, 39, 40];
function onKeydown(event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    for (var i = 0, len =  keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (e.keyCode == keys[i]) {
            console.log("Forbidden event");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}

document.onkeydown = onKeydown;
```

Then you can construct your code by using anchor points and on click advanced to the desired place. That's it.